# FFMpeg: CFLAGS=-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS ./configure where?

Tags: ffmpeg

I got this problem "    'UINT64_C' was not declared in this scope" while using the ffmpeg library for Eclipse running under Ubuntu.

After a while, I have found this solution: http://code.google.com/p/ffmpegsource/issues/detail?id=11

But I could not know how to this:

This should be fixed in our build system no matter what version of ffmpeg you're using. If you're still getting it, run configure like so:
CFLAGS=-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS ./configure
and your problems should go away. This applies to other C++ programs using ffmpeg as well and not just to ffms2, but I can't guarantee that other programs won't break if you define that macro (they really shouldn't, though).

Where can I run the configure? from Terminal? I tried with Terminal but it does not work.

Anybody has an idea how to run the configure?

Thanks in advance and your help is much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run in directory, where you have ffmpeg sources extracted and you see "configure" file

Comment: Hi Fazo, Thanks for your answer but I could not locate the ffmpeg folder. It is under usr/include/ so, how could I locate to this folder in ubuntu? Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to find directory location in project explorer under eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

UINT64_C macro is defined in standard C header stdint.h, but only for non-cplusplus compiled code.

In your source code that uses ffmpeg APIs, try adding the following **before** including any ffmpeg header files:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define __STDINT_MACROS
extern "C" {
#endif
```

That did the trick in a "cleaner" way for me. Hope it helps!