# Get rid of missing -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been searching for a solution to get rid of missing `-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` message in Visual studio express 2013 to no avail. I already have included stdint.h and inttypes. Within the common.h header file here http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/common_8h_source.html there on line 29 there is a following part

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS) && !defined(UINT64_C)
#error missing -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS / #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
```

However, it appears that `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` is defined in the stdint.h. But I still get the error. the source I am trying to compile is here:
http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html

Thanks,

Comment: Related: [FFMpeg: CFLAGS=-D\_\_STDC\_CONSTANT\_MACROS ./configure where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010345/ffmpeg-cflags-d-stdc-constant-macros-configure-where) [Using FFMPeg with VS2010 express](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16586437/332733)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do \_\_STDC\_LIMIT\_MACROS and \_\_STDC\_CONSTANT\_MACROS mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986426/what-do-stdc-limit-macros-and-stdc-constant-macros-mean)

Comment: @Mgetz; That solution is for Ubuntu not Visual Studio.

Comment: @HansPassant: That Solution explains what `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS`is all about and to define `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` before stint.h but it doesn't say How to define it. Also, as I said in my question it appears that it is defined in stdint.h.

Answer (score 6):

-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS error was solved by:
project properties -------> configuration properties -------> c/c++ ----->command line

at additional option enter:
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

that is what  worked for me hope it will help someone else